# angular-ui-router runtime state

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I've got an Angular app with @uirouter. I'd like to dynamically load states based on user e.g. if user is in a specific group and clicks on specific menu item that routes to feature, then I'd like to load alternative implementation of feature module.

State name will be the same so I've tried using uiRouter.stateRegistry.deregister and uiRouter.stateRegistry.register to handle this. I make relevant calls when user logs in, on transition from login to the application (as I need to know user credentials) - for that I'm using uiRouter.transitionService.onBefore. So, code is roughly:

```
    uiRouter.transitionService.onBefore({}, transition => loginTransition(uiRouter, injector, transition));

    const isLogin = transition => transition.from().name === 'login' && transition.to().name === 'main';
    const isRefresh = transition => transition.from().url === '^';

    const loginTransition = (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector, transition: Transition) => {
      if(isLogin(transition) || isRefresh(transition)) {  
        if(injector.get('authService').getUser() === 'specificUser') {
          uiRouter.stateRegistry.deregister('feature-version-1');
          uiRouter.stateRegistry.register('feature-version-2');
        }
      }
    }
```

This works fine when transitioning into app and then navigating to feature. It also works with page refresh when user isn't on feature page. 
Problem is that it doesn't work when user refreshes when on feature page - then feature-version-1 loads instead of feature-version-2. But, when navigating to other page and going back to feature page, feature-version-2 loads again.

This behavior makes me think that while (de)register functionality of stateRegistry works in simple scenario inside transitionService.onBefore, generally using (de)register isn't suited to be used here? Or maybe I'm missing some sort of state refresh call?

Can someone shed some light on this one? When is it best to use (de)register functionality of stateRegistry?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out so I'm sharing in case someone encounters similar problem. Trick is to call stateRegistry inside function passed to UIRouterModule.forChild() which will handle page load/refresh.

```
const register = (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector) => {
   if(injector.get('authService').getUser() === 'specificUser') {
      uiRouter.stateRegistry.deregister('feature-version-1');
      uiRouter.stateRegistry.register('feature-version-2');
    }
}

UIRouterModule.forChild({
    states: [/* states here */],
    config: (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector, module: StatesModule) => {
       register(uiRouter, injector);
       uiRouter.transitionService.onBefore({from:'login', to:'main'}, transition => register(uiRouter, injector));
    }
  })
```